# Could not resolve property of : entity for property in composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a composite key for class AccountMessage, which is accountId and messageId. My code is as below

```
@Embeddable
public class AccountMessagePK implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    /** Serial Version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", nullable = false , insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @JoinColumn(name = "messageId", nullable = false , insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private Message message;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "accountId", nullable = false  )
    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;

    }

    public void setAccount(final Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "messageId", nullable = false  )
    public Message getMessage() {
        return this.message;

    }
    public void setMessage(final Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

The Account entity is like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    /** Serial Version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Integer id = 0;
    private String externalId;

    .....


    public Account() {

    } 

    public Account(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account(Integer id, String externalId, Boolean isDeleted) {

        this.id = id;
        this.externalId = externalId;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }



@Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( name = "externalId", length = 40  )
    public String getExternalId() {
        return this.externalId;

    }


    public void setExternalId(final String externalId) {
        this.externalId = externalId;
    }

@Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "accountId", nullable = false  )
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;

    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

......

}
```

However, when i try to use Hibernate criteria to fetch AccountMessage as below,

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(AccountMessage.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id.account.externalId", filterValue));
crit.list();
```

I got an error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id.account.externalId of: package.path.AccountMessage
```

I googled online and see people get same error but the solution seems not work on my case.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.